# Какую библиотеку использовать при создании gui на win?

Tags: windows, gui

Какую библиотеку использовать при создании gui на win?

Comment: а кстати либа именно под python ??

Comment: А кстати много. Не учитывая winAPI навскидку: tkinter, gtk, qt, wxWindows (далее затрудняюсь перечислять)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это от ваших целей зависит. Если нужно что-нибудь простое по интерфейсу и важна скорость работы , то пойдет [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/). Пример коммерческого интерфейса на WTL - Google Chrome. Если нужно что-нибудь сложное по интерфейсу и важна скорость разработки, то пойдет [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms754130.aspx). Пример коммерческого интерфейса на WPF - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.